# -O2 in ICC messes up assembler, fine with -O1 in ICC and all optimizations in GCC / Clang

Tags: c++, assembly, compiler-optimization, intrinsics, icc

I was recently starting to use ICC (18.0.1.126) to compile a code that worked fine with GCC and Clang on arbitrary optimization settings. The code contains an assembler routine that multiplies 4x4 matrices of doubles using AVX2 and FMA instructions. After much fiddling it turned out that the assembler routine is working properly when compiled with -O1 - xcore-avx2, but gives a wrong numerical result when compiled with -O2 - xcore-avx2. The code compiles however without any error messages on all optimization settings. It runs on an early 2015 MacBook Air with Broadwell core i5.

I also have several versions of the 4x4 matrix multiplication routine originally written for speed testing, with / without FMA, and using assembler / intrinsics. It is the same problem for all of them.

I pass to the routine a pointer to the first element of a 4x4 array of doubles which was created as 
    double MatrixDummy[4][4];
and passed to the routine as
   (&MatrixDummy)[0][0]

The assembler routine is here:

```
//Routine multiplies the 4x4 matrices A * B and store the result in C
inline void RunAssembler_FMA_UnalignedCopy_MultiplyMatrixByMatrix(double *A, double *B, double *C)
{
__asm__ __volatile__  ("vmovupd %0, %%ymm0 \n\t"
                       "vmovupd %1, %%ymm1 \n\t"
                       "vmovupd %2, %%ymm2 \n\t"
                       "vmovupd %3, %%ymm3"
                       :
                       :
                       "m" (B[0]),
                       "m" (B[4]),
                       "m" (B[8]),
                       "m" (B[12])
                       :
                       "ymm0", "ymm1", "ymm2", "ymm3");


__asm__ __volatile__ ("vbroadcastsd %1, %%ymm4 \n\t"
                      "vbroadcastsd %2, %%ymm5 \n\t"
                      "vbroadcastsd %3, %%ymm6 \n\t"
                      "vbroadcastsd %4, %%ymm7 \n\t"
                      "vmulpd %%ymm4, %%ymm0, %%ymm8 \n\t"
                      "vfmadd231PD %%ymm5, %%ymm1, %%ymm8 \n\t"
                      "vfmadd231PD %%ymm6, %%ymm2, %%ymm8 \n\t"
                      "vfmadd231PD %%ymm7, %%ymm3, %%ymm8 \n\t"
                      "vmovupd %%ymm8, %0"
                      :
                      "=m" (C[0])
                      :
                      "m" (A[0]),
                      "m" (A[1]),
                      "m" (A[2]),
                      "m" (A[3])
                      :
                      "ymm4", "ymm5", "ymm6", "ymm7", "ymm8");

__asm__ __volatile__ ("vbroadcastsd %1, %%ymm4 \n\t"
                      "vbroadcastsd %2, %%ymm5 \n\t"
                      "vbroadcastsd %3, %%ymm6 \n\t"
                      "vbroadcastsd %4, %%ymm7 \n\t"
                      "vmulpd %%ymm4, %%ymm0, %%ymm8 \n\t"
                      "vfmadd231PD %%ymm5, %%ymm1, %%ymm8 \n\t"
                      "vfmadd231PD %%ymm6, %%ymm2, %%ymm8 \n\t"
                      "vfmadd231PD %%ymm7, %%ymm3, %%ymm8 \n\t"
                      "vmovupd %%ymm8, %0"
                      :
                      "=m" (C[4])
                      :
                      "m" (A[4]),
                      "m" (A[5]),
                      "m" (A[6]),
                      "m" (A[7])
                      :
                      "ymm4", "ymm5", "ymm6", "ymm7", "ymm8");

__asm__ __volatile__ ("vbroadcastsd %1, %%ymm4 \n\t"
                      "vbroadcastsd %2, %%ymm5 \n\t"
                      "vbroadcastsd %3, %%ymm6 \n\t"
                      "vbroadcastsd %4, %%ymm7 \n\t"
                      "vmulpd %%ymm4, %%ymm0, %%ymm8 \n\t"
                      "vfmadd231PD %%ymm5, %%ymm1, %%ymm8 \n\t"
                      "vfmadd231PD %%ymm6, %%ymm2, %%ymm8 \n\t"
                      "vfmadd231PD %%ymm7, %%ymm3, %%ymm8 \n\t"
                      "vmovupd %%ymm8, %0"
                      :
                      "=m" (C[8])
                      :
                      "m" (A[8]),
                      "m" (A[9]),
                      "m" (A[10]),
                      "m" (A[11])
                      :
                      "ymm4", "ymm5", "ymm6", "ymm7", "ymm8");


__asm__ __volatile__ ("vbroadcastsd %1, %%ymm4 \n\t"
                      "vbroadcastsd %2, %%ymm5 \n\t"
                      "vbroadcastsd %3, %%ymm6 \n\t"
                      "vbroadcastsd %4, %%ymm7 \n\t"
                      "vmulpd %%ymm4, %%ymm0, %%ymm8 \n\t"
                      "vfmadd231PD %%ymm5, %%ymm1, %%ymm8 \n\t"
                      "vfmadd231PD %%ymm6, %%ymm2, %%ymm8 \n\t"
                      "vfmadd231PD %%ymm7, %%ymm3, %%ymm8 \n\t"
                      "vmovupd %%ymm8, %0"
                      :
                      "=m" (C[12])
                      :
                      "m" (A[12]),
                      "m" (A[13]),
                      "m" (A[14]),
                      "m" (A[15])
                      :
                      "ymm4", "ymm5", "ymm6", "ymm7", "ymm8");

}
```

As a comparison, the following code is supposed to do the exact same thing, and does so using all compilers / optimization settings. Since everything works if I use this routine instead of the assembler one, I would expect that the error has to be in how ICC handles the assembler routine with -O2 optimization.

```
inline void Run3ForLoops_MultiplyMatrixByMatrix_OutputTo3(double *A, double *B, double *C){

int i, j, k;

double dummy[4][4];

for(j=0; j<4; j++) {
    for(k=0; k<4; k++) {
        dummy[j][k] = 0.0;
        for(i=0; I<4; i++) {
            dummy[j][k] += *(A+j*4+i)*(*(B+i*4+k));
        }
    }
}

for(j=0; j<4; j++) {
    for(k=0; k<4; k++) {
        *(C+j*4+k) = dummy[j][k];
    }
}


}
```

Any ideas? I am really confused.

Comment: As I don't have ICC for myself, have you tried inspecting the generated assembly?   I suppose the problem could be related to you using a `"=m"` output constraint but then violating it by reading from `%0` before writing to it.

Comment: What you may also try to do is see if the problem persists when you use the vector intrinsics provided by x86intrin.h, instead of writing the assembler code directly.

Comment: Let me just add that I am new to assembly and this is my first project, so there may be some problems in the code. The problem above persists if I use vector intrinsics provided in xmmintrin.h, which is included in x86intrin.h. Inspecting the assembly didn't help as I am new to the business.

Comment: @fuz: Could you elaborate on the problem with the "=m" output constraint? As far as I see it, I only read from %0 in the first block.

Comment: @Denton An output constraint beginning with `=` indicates that you only ever write to the operand.  Reading from it is a violation of the constraint and the compiler is not obliged to preserve its value.  To get an output operand you can also read from, use `+` instead of `=`, i.e. `"+m"`. Refer to [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) for details.

Comment: @Denton You could at least post the assembly generated by ICC for both optimization levels so we have any chance at all to understand what went wrong.  Not all of us have an ICC license.

Comment: @fuz: https://gcc.godbolt.org/ has ICC installed so we can could look at the asm if we wanted to see exactly what went wrong with the OP's bogus asm that assumes register values survive between separate asm statements.

Comment: I strongly advice you to read the whole manual I linked before writing any inline assembly.  You do some rookie mistakes (e.g. assuming that registers keep their values between assembly statements) that come from an incomplete understanding of how inline assembly should be used.

Comment: @Denton Sorry about the constraint thing.  Reading your assembly again, it is not actually wrong.  I just confused `%%ymm0` and `%0`.

Comment: In your first asm statement, `"ymm0", "ymm1", "ymm2", "ymm3"` are outputs (and inputs to the later ones).  I assume ICC violates your assumption that the compiler won't use those registers.  Or possibly it violates your assumption that reading compiler about `B[1..3]` along with `B[0]` is safe without telling the compiler about it.  (You've only told the compiler you're reading one `double` from each of those memory operands, not 4.  You can do `"m"(*(__m256*)(&B[0]))` or something.

Comment: *The problem above persists if I use vector intrinsics provided in xmmintrin.h*.  That's extremely surprising if you used them correctly.  Did you actually replace your whole asm code with `_mm256_set1_ps(A[0])` and so on?  It would be extremely weird for ICC to have a code-gen bug for intrinsics that matched whatever you got from inlining this function with asm statements into whatever you called it from.

Comment: @fuz: I just checked ICC on Godbolt myself.  Presumably the problem comes when inlining into some unknown caller; it looks like a stand-alone version of the function compiles as expected.   (I had to remove `inline`, otherwise we get an empty asm output :P)

Comment: @PeterCordes ICC complained about not finding `-lm` (after finding the button that shows the compiler output).  Perhaps it was not installed correctly?  I fixed this issue, though now I can confirm that the assembly generated is identical (module code alignment) in the two optimization levels.  OP really needs to show us his compiler output or this is going nowhere.

Comment: @fuz: Oh, you tried the "binary" mode?  Yeah I see that problem, too.  Install problems are unfortunately common on Godbolt; it's a lot of compilers to maintain in Matt's spare time, especially binary mode.  I think we can trust ICC's asm output, though, and only need binary to make sure it actually assembles correctly when using inline asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes Hm... good idea.  It is possible that the compiler decides to schedule some variable loads between the assembly blocks.  After all, OPs clobber lists are incomplete and even a complete clobber list is not a guarantee that the registers keep their values between ASM statements. Though strictly speaking, the execution of functions may not be interspersed.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, that's what this button does....

Comment: @fuz: Huh?  "strictly speaking" all registers have unknown/garbage values except ones you request as input operands.  The as-if rule allows the compiler to do whatever it wants, spreading your code out after inlining (it's even declared `inline`, so there should be no expectation that it executes on its own).  `asm volatile` might respect ordering wrt. access to `volatile` variables, but I think even that might not be guaranteed.  It can certainly reorder with access to other stuff, because there's no `"memory"` clobber.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168823/discussion-between-fuz-and-peter-cordes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core problem with your code is the assumption that if you write a value to a register, that value is still going to be there in the next statement.  This assumption is wrong.  Between `asm` statements, the compiler may use any register as it likes.  For example, it may decide to use `ymm0` to copy a variable from one location to another between your statements, trashing its previous content.

The correct way to do inline assembly is to never ever refer to registers directly if there is no good reason to do so.  Each value you want to keep between assembly statements needs to be placed in a variable using an appropriate operand.  The [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) is quite clear about this.

As an example, let me rewrite your code to use correct inline assembly:

```
#include <immintrin.h>

inline void RunAssembler_FMA_UnalignedCopy_MultiplyMatrixByMatrix(double *A, double *B, double *C)
{
    size_t i;

    /* the registers you use */
    __m256 a0, a1, a2, a3, b0, b1, b2, b3, sum;
    __m256 *B256 = (__m256 *)B, *C256 = (__m256 *)C;

    /* load values from B */
    asm ("vmovupd %1, %0" : "=x"(b0) : "m"(B256[0]));
    asm ("vmovupd %1, %0" : "=x"(b1) : "m"(B256[1]));
    asm ("vmovupd %1, %0" : "=x"(b2) : "m"(B256[2]));
    asm ("vmovupd %1, %0" : "=x"(b3) : "m"(B256[3]));

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        /* load values from A */
        asm ("vbroadcastsd %1, %0" : "=x"(a0) : "m"(A[4 * i + 0]));
        asm ("vbroadcastsd %1, %0" : "=x"(a1) : "m"(A[4 * i + 1]));
        asm ("vbroadcastsd %1, %0" : "=x"(a2) : "m"(A[4 * i + 2]));
        asm ("vbroadcastsd %1, %0" : "=x"(a3) : "m"(A[4 * i + 3]));

        asm ("vmulpd %2, %1, %0"      : "=x"(sum) : "x"(a0), "x"(b0));
        asm ("vfmadd231pd %2, %1, %0" : "+x"(sum) : "x"(a1), "x"(b1));
        asm ("vfmadd231pd %2, %1, %0" : "+x"(sum) : "x"(a2), "x"(b2));
        asm ("vfmadd231pd %2, %1, %0" : "+x"(sum) : "x"(a3), "x"(b3));
        asm ("vmovupd %1, %0" : "=m"(C256[i]) : "x"(sum));
    }
}
```

There are a bunch of things you should immediately notice:

- every register we use is described abstractly through an asm operand
- all values we save are tied to local variables so the compiler can keep track of which registers are in use and which registers can be clobbered
- since all dependencies and side effects of the asm statements are explicitly described through operands, no `volatile` qualifier is necessary and the compiler can optimize the code much better

Still, you should really consider using intrinsics instead as the compilers can do many more optimizations with intrinsics than they can with inline assembly.  This is because the compiler to some extent understands what the intrinsic does and can use this knowledge to generate better code.

Comment: A good example of how intrinsics are better for this: If you compile with `-mavx512vl` (or `-march=skylake-avx512`), then (hopefully) you'll get a `vfmadd???pd` with a broadcast-memory operand.  (The EVEX encoding can broadcast a scalar as an operand to most ALU instruction)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works for me. I will give the intrinsics another shot. They were slightly slower than the inline assembly on GCC and Clang.

Comment: @Denton Post your code with intrinsics and we can try to help you find out what the problem is.

Comment: Hi fuz. The intrinsics and assembly are posted in the main post above, there is still a problem. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @Denton: The question about your version with intrinsics should really be posted separately.  You can only accept one answer per question, and this is already the answer to this question.  So, roll back your edit and post that material as a new question.  You can link to this one for background instead of copying stuff.

Comment: @Denton Please make a new question for that as it's a separate problem.  I think the problem is related to the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: Ok, done. Question is now here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49858977/o3-in-icc-messes-up-intrinsics-fine-with-o1-or-o2-or-with-corresponding-manu